# Android onclick method in layout doesn't work

Tags: java, android

[image: View This Image]

i am novice to android and having trouble figuring what makes method `showToast()` not working. in the code i've two buttons with two different kind of onclickListeners. the first one which i set **onclick** to by creating object works perfectly but the second button which i applied onclick by going to layout design properties doesn't work . any idea?

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, "Nav's first Toast ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);                                              //this one works
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                toast.show();
                //optional to reposition
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT,45,100);
            }
        });
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////
   public void showToast(View view){
       Toast toast2=Toast.makeText(this, "Nav's Second Toast ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);      //this one doesn't work
       toast2.show();
   }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Just use "showToast" not "showToast(MainActivity)"

Comment: remove (MainActivity), you don't need it. Just write "showToast" that's it.

Comment: THANK YOU !!! thanx a bunch both of you, really helped. god bless

Comment: @NavSandhu glad could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your function you  fire by `XML` code.

simple `showToast` instead of `showToast(....)`:

`android:onClick="showToast"`